# How to avoid force close if there is no data to fetch in db

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having some problem in avoiding force stop of my application. When I click my load button it is supposed to load all data present in my database. However, if there is no data present in my database, I want to display a toast saying that there is no data to fetch in the db.

```
      save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {

                db.addContact(new PlayerData(name,score));
                Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting .."); 

            } 
      });



          load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    List<PlayerData> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
                    //check to ensure there are users
                    if(contacts.size()==0)
                        try {
                            throw new Exception();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    PlayerData player = contacts.get(0);
                    String showName = player.getName();
                    int showScore = player.getscore();
                    Log.d("Getting:", showName);
                    Log.d("Getting:", Integer.toString(showScore));
                    saved.setText("Player Name: "+showName+" Player Score: "+showScore);

                } 
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if(contacts.size()==0)
    try {
        throw new Exception();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Your code ignores the fact there are no contacts and tries to perform actions on said nonexistent contacts. Instead, you should have the Toast display in this if statement and execute the rest of the code in an else block:

```
load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {

            List<PlayerData> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
            //check to ensure there are users
            if(contacts.size()==0) {
                String text = "No contacts in db";
                Toast.makeText(text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                PlayerData player = contacts.get(0);
                String showName = player.getName();
                int showScore = player.getscore();
                Log.d("Getting:", showName);
                Log.d("Getting:", Integer.toString(showScore));
                saved.setText("Player Name: "+showName+" Player Score: "+showScore);
            }
        } 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

1. Instantiate your `List<PlayerData>`
2. Load data from the database
3. Check if you have data in your `List<PlayerData>`. Whether to check for `null` or for `size()==0` depends on the logic you implemented :)
4. If empty, display a `Toast` that there are no players to play with. Else, do whatever you want.

---

Code:

```
load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {

        List<PlayerData> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
        //check to ensure there are users
        if(contacts == null || contacts.size() == 0){
            // do something.
        }else{
            // start the game
            PlayerData player = contacts.get(0);
            String showName = player.getName();
            int showScore = player.getscore();
            Log.d("Getting:", showName);
            Log.d("Getting:", Integer.toString(showScore));
            saved.setText("Player Name: "+showName+" Player Score: "+showScore);
        }
    } 
});
```